# Multiple downloads from public source (web site), how to bypass "click on OK button" triggered by Javascript?

Tags: firefox, download, javascript

I'm trying to download multiple data sets from a public source, the [European Union Transaction Log](http://ec.europa.eu/environment/ets/).

I'm using the "Allocation / Compliance" search tool (in the left blue pane).

From there I must select a country and hit "search". I then have access to various years (2010, 2011, 2012, etc...). I want to download the files for all countries (28) and all previous years (from 2005 to 2013), meaning 252 requests at least.

I tried to figure out how I could directly use the download URL. The final URL (in this instance, for Bulgaria in 2010), is [the following](http://ec.europa.eu/environment/ets/exportEntry.do?form=napYearInformation&napInstallation.installationIdentifier=&installationAllowance=35266538&periodCodeLookup=First+Commitment+Period&languageCode=en&periodYear=2010&resultList.currentPageNumber=1&napInstallation.installationName=&registryCode=BG&registryCodeLookup=Bulgaria&currentSortSettings=&periodCode=1).

From this URL, I can:

- strip the "&installationAllowance=35266538" parameter
- strip the "&registryCodeLookup=Bulgaria" parameter
- change the "&periodYear=2010" parameter (to change the reference date)
- change the "&registryCode=BG" parameter (to change the country).

My only problem so far is that each link requires a validation from the download page (a click on a "OK" button).

In the source code of the page, I see that the function triggered is the following:

```
<form name="export" method="POST" action="http://ec.europa.eu/environment/ets/export.do">
```

The "OK" button code is the following:

```
<input type="submit" name="OK" value="Ok" class="FormButton" id="btnOK">
```

There is also a block of JavaScript in the page source.

How could I mass download these files? (I was thinking of creating a bunch of links, replacing the years and countries with a RegEx, and then using the "DownThemAll" extension for Firefox, with the option "download from file").

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely consider using **python with** module called **selenium**.

You can automate any browser actions easily (even headlessly with [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)).

Simplest example:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

Above code will open the python.org webpage, find element `q`, type in "pycon", hit enter and check if there were any results returned.

You can define some actions chains you want to perform:

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(menu)
actions.click(hidden_submenu)
actions.perform()
```

You can of course find the "OK" button that have to be clicked:

```
button_ok = driver.find_element_by_id('button')
```

and click on it:

```
button_ok.click()
```

Xpaths can be used as well to search for given elements: `/html/body/button`.

If you are interested with this solution consider reviewing [documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) which is very well written and will surely allow you to create the final solution in no time.